# Duplicator does not have enough permission

Tags: php, wordpress

I cannot duplicate my wordpress site to local this is the error message:

```
Fail   [/srv/bindings/16b097b7aa994cd3b3e1a45c65bfaa5c/code/wp-snapshots] 
Fail   [/srv/bindings/16b097b7aa994cd3b3e1a45c65bfaa5c/code/wp-snapshots/tmp] 

If Duplicator does not have enough permissions then you will need to manually create the paths above.   The root WordPress path [/srv/bindings/16b097b7aa994cd3b3e1a45c65bfaa5c/code/] is currently not writable by PHP.
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to manually create those directories using your FTP software (if you don't have direct server access) and chmod them to be writeable by the app. Start with 755 and see if that works, and tweak down from there.

Comment: still permission denied

Comment: What do you all mean by 755 and 777? Windows server IIS? I've already used duplicator on the same files ones. I'm reinstalling but now getting this all of a sudden.